# Known attempts at stack-based memory management for the JVM

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, stack

I'm reading up on different JVM implementations, and I'm wondering why a [stack-based memory management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation) isn't more widespread (not to be confused with [escape analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis)). Are any of you familiar with attempts on writing JVMs with stack-based memory management?

Comment: So can you then also post a link to a resource that describes how object escaping is different from escape analysis? Because the first hit I get when I type "object escaping" in google is the wiki on escape analysis.

Comment: Just ignore the object escaping term - I'm just talking about stack-based memory allocation at runtime. As far as I can see that's different from escape analysis, because the analysis happens at compile-time.

Comment: The JVM logically allocates objects on the heap, and without an escape proof, which wouldn't be possible for a huge number of real-world workloads, a physical heap is the only practical arrangement.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Why is it impossible to create escape proofs for real-world workloads? In theory you could just put all loaded classes in the vm heap and then put new instances on the stack whenever they're created, right?

Comment: You might do that, and then you create a huge pile of impossible to catch bugs. In effect it would have to be made impossible to create additional references to that object on the stack, or the unrolling of the stack would cause all additional references to become defunct automagically.

Comment: Made impossible to create additional references? Why? If you have a thread stack, you'd just allocate the object as soon as it's needed. On a stack (remember it's one-dimensional), you can point reference backwards without any problems, and it should be removed whenever the last object that needs it, dies. The trick is just never to have any references pointing forward on the stack.

Comment: This is just not practical. As soon as you have multithreading, you have the need to share references between threads. This means that threads need to hold references to other threads stacks, and these get invalidated as soon as the method that created the object initially returns.

Comment: Thanks @kittylyst. I don't think I'll get much closer than that. Could you post an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just not really practical.

As soon as you have multithreading, you have the need to share references to objects between threads. This means that threads need to hold references to other threads stacks, and these get invalidated as soon as the method that initially created the object returns.

The heap is effectively the shared area of memory that all threads in a process can see, so any object that needs to be seen by multiple threads naturally lives there.

Another way to say this is that the stack is private to a thread, whereas the heap is shared between them.